# 2 column CSS floating images different sizes

Tags: css, image, css-float, padding, multiple-columns

I have a div that is 250 x 250 px.

I have 6 images I want inside; 2 columns, 3 images in each column.

The images will be two sizes: 80px wide, or 110px wide... but the heights vary.

Is it possible to achieve something like this; where the padding will adjust fluidly between the different image sizes to fill the div?  I would like to avoid having more than two image classes; just one for 80 and one for 110.

[image]

Comment: You looking for something like this? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYXXVX

Comment: my markup is a mess right now... I was embarrassed to even show it.  I assumed someone here could show me the right way to build it.  @Justin Breiland - trying this now!

Comment: @Justin Breiland - this is perfect - works like a charm.  Thank you sir!

Comment: @JustinBreiland  does this work in IE?  Having a little trouble in IE... other browsers are fine though

Comment: It should work in IE 10+, in 10 you need the -ms- prefix.  Should have put that in there for you my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Use flex box : http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ with that code :

```
flex-direction: column;
align-content: space-around; //or space-between;
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is what Justin posted above as well.   I wasn't aware of this method - thanks for sharing!